# Numpy.select from 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

Suppose I have the following numpy arrays:

```
>>a
array([[0, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 1]])
>>b
array([[2, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 2]])
```

that I then vertically stack

```
c=np.dstack((a,b))
```

resulting in:

```
>>c
array([[[0, 2],
        [0, 2],
        [2, 0]],

       [[2, 2],
        [0, 0],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [1, 2]]])
```

From this I wish to, for each 3rd dimension of c, check which combination is present in this subarray, and then number it accordingingly with the index of the list-match. I've tried the following, but it is not working. The algorithm is simple enough with double for-loops, but because c is very large, it is prohibitively slow.

```
classes=[(0,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
out=np.select( [h==c for h in classes], range(len(classes)), default=-1)
```

My desired output would be

```
out = [[-1,-1,-1],
       [3,  1,-1],
       [2,  2,-1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
(np.array([np.array(h)[...,:] == c for h in classes]).all(axis = -1) *
         (2 + np.arange(len(classes)))[:, None, None]).max(axis=0) - 1
```

It returns, what you actually need

```
array([[-1, -1, -1],
       [ 3,  1, -1],
       [ 2,  2, -1]])
```

Comment: This looks like it has the flexibility I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can test the a and b arrays separately like this:

```
clsa = (0,2,2)
clesb = (0,1,2)

np.select ( [(ca==a) & (cb==b) for ca,cb in zip (clsa, clsb)], range (3), default = -1)
```

which gets your desired result (except returns 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,3).

Comment: Not quite the flexibility I need, but nice to learn a different way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get what you want, thought I would post it in case it's useful to anyone.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 2],
              [2, 0, 1],
              [2, 2, 1]])
b = np.array([[2, 2, 0],
              [2, 0, 2],
              [1, 1, 2]])
classes=[(0,0),(2,1),(2,2)]

c = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=[('a', a.dtype), ('b', b.dtype)])
c['a'] = a
c['b'] = b
classes = np.array(classes, dtype=c.dtype)
classes.sort()
out = classes.searchsorted(c)
out = np.where(c == classes[out], out+1, -1)
print out
#array([[-1, -1, -1]
#       [ 3,  1, -1]
#       [ 2,  1, -1]])
```